# drag to share module

Tags: drupal-6

I can't use the drag to share module. I downloaded and enabled it. But then my content page goes 'blank'. It doesn't show anything. Somebody help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was the problem enabling the jquery UI required for the above module. It worked after proper installation of folders required for the jquery UI.

I downloaded the jquery UI interface and bagan putting the jquery UI plugin in it (for more details go through the readme.txt file of the module). But the link provided in the readme.txt file is outdated and does not provide the required folder. This folder has now been downloaded from : http://github.com/facebook/platform/tree/master/clients/packages/ and the both the modules(drag to share & jquery UI) are successfully working.